# EasyAdminBundle - Unrecognized option "sort" under "easy_admin.list"

Tags: symfony, sorting, symfony2-easyadmin

I've been looking for a way to override the default sorting of data which is based on primary key.

I found some configuration examples for sorting data from the documentation but it doesn't work.

It says

> Unrecognized option "sort" under "easy_admin.list"

```
easy_admin:
   entities:
      Customer:
          class: AppBundle\Entity\Customer
          list:
              sort: 'name'
          form:
              title: 'Add Customer'
              form_options: {validation_groups:['Default']}

              fields:
                  - name
                  - {property: 'gender', type: 'choice', type_options:
                                                  {
                                                    placeholder: 'Select your gender',
                                                    choices: {
                                                        Female: 'female',
                                                        Male: 'male'
                                                    }
                                                  } }
                  - {property: 'birthdate', type: 'date', type_options: {widget: 'single_text'}}
                  - isActive
          new:
              form_options: {validation_groups: ['Default','Customer']}
          edit:
              title: 'Edit Customer'

site_name: 'Premiere Sales'
```

Comment: where did you find that example?

Answer (score 1):

You use `sort` option in the wrong place. You should set `sort` option under your entity scope of configuration:

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        User:
            # ...
            list:
                # if the sort order is not specified, 'DESC' is used
                sort: 'createdAt'
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't take effect. I'll update my question with the configuration

Comment: In your updated question you don't have any problems. But the error message that you posted earlier says that you used `sort` option just under `easy_admin` section.

Comment: Yes I tweak the configuration after what you've suggested and it works.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the configuration I posted above is correct and I just restarted the server and the browser and it works fine